# MemoryMappedFileSecurity missing in .NET 6

Tags: c#, access-denied, memory-mapped-files, .net-6.0

I have a service that makes use of MemoryMappedFiles for interprocess communication.  It has worked great for many years and was developed in .NET Framework 4.6.1.   Now comes the time to port the code to .NET 6.  I've gotten the bulk of it to work correctly except for one issue: the security ACL for the memory mapped file.  That argument seems to have disappeared in .NET 6.
Here is a snippet from the 4.6.1 Framework version

```
    fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    FileSecurity fSec = File.GetAccessControl(FileName);
    fSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
    File.SetAccessControl(FileName, fSec);
    if (fs.Length == 0)
        fs.SetLength(_SectionSize);
    long fLen = fs.Length;
    MemoryMappedFileSecurity security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
    security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
    //Name = @"Global\DCCCache";    // "Global\" when running as a service so session 0 stuff available to everyone
    _MMFHandle = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs, Name, _SectionSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, security, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, false);
    _VAHandle = _MMFHandle.CreateViewAccessor();
```

This all works and allows non-admin user processes access to the memory mapped file.
.NET 6 drops the **security** argument from the `.CreateFromFile` method.  As a result, only processes running with Administrator privileges have access to the memory mapped file.   An "Access Denied" IO exception is thrown from the `OpenExisting` method of `MemoryMappedFile` for non-admin processes.

Is there a way to modify the security when I create a memory mapped file so non-admin processes have access?

Comment: Did you look at the [proposal to add it to .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/941)?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The discussion looks like the feature is specifically missing from 6, with a desire to add it.  Unless I didn't see it, there's been no movement lately on implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

I did a workaround.  Put together the call I needed to create the memory mapped file with the correct security and call it once in the service that owns it.  I changed the mainline code to use `OpenExisting` after the call to the routine below so the remainder of the code can use the .NET 6 library as intended. Not ideal, but it fixed the issue.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace MMFService {
    internal class MMFNet6Shim : IDisposable {
        private bool win32Result = false;
        private int cbSid = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
        private SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        private SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle hFile;

        private const int SDDL_REVISION_1 = 1;
        private const int SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE = 68;
        private const int PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;
        private const int FILE_MAP_WRITE = 0X02;

        public MMFNet6Shim(FileStream fs, string DBName) {
            win32Result = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor("D:(A;OICI;GA;;;WD)", SDDL_REVISION_1, out securityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (!win32Result)
                throw new Exception("ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            securityAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(securityAttributes);
            securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = false;
            long fLen = fs.Length;
            hFile = CreateFileMapping(fs.SafeFileHandle, ref securityAttributes, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fLen), DBName);
            if (hFile.IsInvalid) 
                throw new Exception("CreateFileMapping", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if(!hFile.IsInvalid)
                hFile.Close();
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor
        (
        [In] string StringSecurityDescriptor,
        [In] int StringSDRevision,
        [Out] out IntPtr SecurityDescriptor,
        [Out] IntPtr SecurityDescriptorSize
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr LocalFree([In] IntPtr hMem);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle CreateFileMapping(
        [In] SafeFileHandle hFile,
        [In][Optional] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpAttributes,
        [In] int flProtect,
        [In] int dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        [In] int dwMaximumSizeLow,
        [In][Optional] string lpName
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set access for Everyone:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSecurityInfo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
    SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern uint SetSecurityInfoByHandle(SafeHandle handle, uint objectType, uint securityInformation,
    byte[]? owner, byte[]? group, byte[]? dacl, byte[]? sacl);
```

then

```
            mmfile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Global\\jdfghdfghsd", requiredsize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
        if (SetSecurityInfoByHandle(mmfile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle, 1, 4, null, null, null, null) != 0)
            throw new Exception("MemoryMappedFile set security failed");
```

Set customized access rights if required, look at SetSecurityInfo help

So, sample apps:

App1:

```
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSecurityInfo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
    SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SetSecurityInfoByHandle(SafeHandle handle, uint objectType, uint securityInformation,
    byte[]? owner, byte[]? group, byte[]? dacl, byte[]? sacl);
var mmfile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Global\\dsfgsdfsdf", 4, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
if (SetSecurityInfoByHandle(mmfile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle, 1, 4, null, null, null, null) != 0)
    throw new Exception("Access rights set up failed");
mmfile.CreateViewAccessor(0, 4).Write(0, 234);
Console.ReadLine();
```

App2:

```
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
Console.WriteLine(MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Global\\dsfgsdfsdf", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite).CreateViewAccessor(0, 4).ReadInt32(0));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Run app1, then app2. It should emit 234. Then press Enter for app1.
Be sure the user runs app1 is able to create the global objects (by default only administrators and services are allowed)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: It works in my app.

Comment: can you give me full source code? thanks

Comment: What particular doesn't work? I put sample apps in my answer. Same samples can be found in Internet.